# Is it possible to add an ID to a HTML-Tag locally in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Good morning,

I don´t even have a problem but I am curious, is it possible to add an ID to a HTML-Tag locally in angular. So that only the component which defines it is able to access it? My idea is to set the id and access it later in the JS-Function. But I´m afraid that could lead to more than one result when calling document.getElementById(this.configurationHeader.id.toString());.

(like the button in the code below)

Kind regards
Paul

```js
changeFavoriteApperance() {
  let _isFavorite = this.browserStorage.idIsFavorite(this.configurationHeader.id);
  let _button = document.getElementById(this.configurationHeader.id.toString());
  let _id = [];
  _id.push(this.configurationHeader.id);

  _button.style.color = _isFavorite ? 'yellow' : 'inherit';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4 class="child name">{{configurationHeader.name}}</h4>
  <p class="child description">{{configurationHeader.description}}</p>
  <button name="favorite" class="favorite" (click)="this.changeFavoriteStatus()" id={{this.configurationHeader.id}}>⚝</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you can define a dynamic ID and set it to any HTML tag. What exactly do you want to achieve through that though? Other components will still, in theory, have access to the entire DOM. If you want to "listen" to events issued by the user on that very element, there's better ways (event-handlers).

Comment: Nope, I just want a unique ID which refers to tag in the DOM. Which is not used by another component.

Comment: why don't you use viewchild?

Comment: Siggi, use document.getElementById mush be forbidden in Angular :). More seriously, if you use a template reference https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#template-reference-variables-var, you can get the element ref in your code.e.g. using `ViewChild('yourVariable') myElement:ElementRef` you has the element in myElement.nativeElement, using ViewChildren you get a QueryList of elements... In .html you can use this template reference variable to pass as argument of another function. Really use document.getElementById is a poor idea

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the interpolation in double quotes. And the `this` keyword isn't required.

```html
<button 
  name="favorite" 
  class="favorite"
  (click)="changeFavoriteStatus()"
  id="{{configurationHeader.id}}"
>⚝</button>
```

Alternatively you could bind to the attribute property using `[id]="configurationHeader.id"`.

However in Angular, there are better ways to handle tag specific properties instead of dynamically modifying the `id`.

Comment: Ok, my bad i didn´t clarify that. I wanna manipulate it with JS later like this. And thats fine but i´m afraid this could lead to multiple results when calling document.getElementById();.

changeFavoriteApperance(){
    let _isFavorite = this.browserStorage.idIsFavorite(this.configurationHeader.id);
    let _button = document.getElementById(this.configurationHeader.id.toString());
    let _id = [];
    _id.push(this.configurationHeader.id);
    
    _button.style.color = _isFavorite ? 'yellow' : 'inherit';
  }

Comment: Why do you have to do it in JS? You could achieve it directly in Angular.